# What to do when somebody posts the same answer in different way?

Tags: support, flags

I have posted an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325606/android-scrolling-of-a-scrollview). Here somebody posted an answer that is the same as mine. I mean it gives the same result as mine. What to do - which flag should I use in this kind of situation?

Comment: Those two answers look different to me. You both moved things around, but in different ways. Then again, I don't code in XML so I could be completely wrong. Plus, his explained what he did more than yours did, so I don't see much similarity here.

Comment: Yes it Looks different but output is same

Comment: In addition, the other answer has some explanatory prose, whereas yours is a block of code.

Comment: Plus, according to the other answer: *you must declare the edittext/button above where you declare the scrollview*. Yours does not do that, so it can't be plagiarism in my opinion. The other answer or yours just may be wrong.

Comment: @Anonymous Positioning of widgets not affecting on the result this is not C language and Line by Line execution.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot Both of your answers changed positioning, so I don't really understand your point. Anyway, I'm going to stop now before this turns into an argument.

Comment: @Anonymous Apologies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flags for similar answers will be declined. You're both answering the same question. You should expect answers to be similar and to have similar results.

Answer (score 4):

There are only so many sane ways to write a program. Often the best programmers will come up with virtually identical answers to the same problem, if the problem doesn't allow for much variation. There's nothing that needs to be done here.